# Bad practice to have models made up of other models?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a situation where I have Model A that has a variety of properties. I have discovered that some of the properties are similar across other models. My thought was I could create Model B and Model C and have Model A be a composite with a Model B property and a Model C property.

Just trying to determine if this is the best way to handle this situation.

Comment: Isn't this just *inheritance*? I think this is what the language was designed for.

Comment: Not really ... as I would like Model A to have a property of type Model B and Model C. For example, Model B handles customer information, and Model C handles project information. Model A, a task, would have a property of Model B and Model C. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely valid in certain situations. Let's say you have a `Person` class and a `Company` class, and they have the common properties `streetNumber`, `streetName`, `postcode`, etc. It makes sense to make a new model class called `Address` that both `Person` and `Company` contain. Inheritance is the completely wrong way to go in such a situation.

Answer (score 1):

When properties (e.g. **state**) are the elements of commonality, I definately tend towards using composition rather than inheritance.  When using inheritance, its perhaps best to wait until **behavior** is the commonality, and overrides are needed now or imminently.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking at is creating an [Aggregate Root](http://thinkddd.com/blog/2009/02/14/aggregates-and-aggregate-roots/). A core paradigm of the [Domain Driven Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) (DDD) principals.

Certain models in your app will appear to belong "at the top" or "as root" to other objects. For example in the case of customers you might have a `Contact` model which then contains a collection of `ContactPoint`s (names, addresses, etc).
Or a `Post` (in the case of a blog), which contains a collection of `Comment`s, a Tite, Body and a `TagSet` (for tagging). Notice how the items i've `highlighted` as objects - these are other model types as opposed to simple types (`string`s, `int`s, etc).

The trick will come when and how you decide to 'fill' these Aggregate Root trees/graphs. Ie. How will you query just for a single `TagSet`? Will you go to the top and get the corresponding `Post` first? Maybe you just wanted to rename the tag "aspnetmvc" to "asp.net-mvc" for all `Post`s so you want to cut in and just get the `TagSet` item.

The [MVC Storefront](http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/) tutorial has some good examples of this pattern. Take a look if you can.